# Symfony Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, silex

I try to convert this query to the querybuilder:

```
SELECT *, landingpages_content.id as cid FROM `landingpages_content` LEFT JOIN content ON landingpages_content.content_id = content.id WHERE content.enabled = 1 AND landingpages_content.landingpage_id = ? ORDER BY landingpages_content.`order`
```

This is my QueryBuilder code:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('*, landingpages_content.id as cid')
    ->from('landingpages_content', 'landingpages_content')
    ->leftJoin('landingpages_content.content_id', 'content.id', null)
    ->where('content.enabled = 1')
    ->andWhere('landingpages_content.landingpage_id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', $id)
    ->orderBy('landingpages_content.`order`', 'ASC');
```

It returns

> InvalidArgumentException: The query builder cannot have joins.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `leftJoin` method wrong. Try something like this:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('*, landingpages_content.id as cid')
    ->from('landingpages_content', 'landingpages_content')
    ->leftJoin('landingpages_content.content', 'content', 'ON', 'landingpages_content.content_id = content.id')
    ->where('content.enabled = 1')
    ->andWhere('landingpages_content.landingpage_id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', $id)
    ->orderBy('landingpages_content.order', 'ASC');
```

Comment: Well, that's odd, I can't find such error in Symfony code. Can you point out by what code this exception is thrown ?

Comment: It's not caused by symfony. It's caused by [link](https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta/blob/master/src/Pagerfanta/Adapter/DoctrineDbalSingleTableAdapter.php)

Comment: I don't know Pagerfanta but apparently it's quite straightforward - `The query builder cannot have joins.`. Your queryBuilder does have join so it can't be handled by Pagerfanta